# ffmpeg produce flickering video for same image sequence, what's wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, ffmpeg, python-imaging-library

This is my sample code ,every single frame is the same , the output file is a static video.

```
import numpy as np
import subprocess

ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ffmpeg", '-y', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-vcodec', 'mjpeg', '-s', '300x300', '-i', '-', '-an', '-r', '24', '-pix_fmt',
     'gray', 'video.mp4'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
gray = np.identity(300, np.uint8) * 255
for i in range(100):
    import PIL.Image

    PIL.Image.fromarray(gray).save(ffmpeg_process.stdin, "JPEG")
    ffmpeg_process.stdin.flush()
ffmpeg_process.stdin.close()
ffmpeg_process.communicate()
```

But when I trid to pass the image as rawvideo instead of 'jpeg' ,the output is a flikcering video .

```
import numpy as np
import subprocess

ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ffmpeg", '-y', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-s', '300x300', '-i', '-', '-an', '-r', '24', '-pix_fmt', 'gray', 'video.mp4'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
gray = np.identity(300, np.uint8) * 255
for i in range(100):
    ffmpeg_process.stdin.write(gray.tobytes())
    ffmpeg_process.stdin.flush()
ffmpeg_process.stdin.close()
ffmpeg_process.communicate()
```

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: You have to specify the correct pixel format for the input using `-pixel format` placed before `-i`.

Comment: @Gyan I tried -pixel_format and -pxi_fmt ,both worked ,what's the difference ?